# jQuery JSON database variable applied in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

This could be an easy task but I am just learning the relationship between jQuery, JSON, and Javascript. I used jQuery to to pull from my database and create a variable called res[i].showlink which is a url. Here is part of my code for the call.

```
   $.get("http://databasecall=json", {}, function (res) {
       $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
       if (res.length) {
           var s = "";
           for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
               s += "<li><a name=" + res[i].id + " href='" + "javascript:openGoogle()" + "'>" + res[i].showlink + "</a></li>";
           }
           $("#showList").html(s);
           $("#showList").listview("refresh")
       }, "json");
```

The problem is that I would like reuse the res[i].showlink database variable in a javascript function (openGoogle) outside of the code above. When I go to reuse the database variable res[i].showlink, it no longer contains my data from the database. How can I reuse the variable outside of the jQuery/JSON code above? I really appreciate any suggestions. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are storing that value as the contents of the anchor tag, you can access it from there too.

change

```
javascript:openGoogle()
```

to

```
javascript:openGoogle.apply(this)
```

and then inside of `openGoogle`, you can access the value with `$(this).text()`

**Edit**
Another option is to pass the value directly as a parameter.

change

```
javascript:openGoogle()
```

to

```
javascript:openGoogle(" + res[i].showlink + )
```

and then modify

```
function openGoogle() {
```

to

```
function openGoogle(showlink) {
```

and access the value with

```
alert(showlink);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to store a reference to `res` outside of the `get` call--otherwise, it's scoped and, as you noticed, you can't access it from outside the call. Try something like this:

```
var globalRes = null;

$.get("http://databasecall=json", {}, function(res) {
    globalRes = res;
    $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
    if (res.length) {
        var s = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {

            s += "<li><a name=" + res[i].id + " href='" + "javascript:openGoogle()" + "'>" + res[i].showlink + "</a></li>";

        }
        $("#showList").html(s);
        $("#showList").listview("refresh")
    }, "json");​
```

After the call, `globalRes` will contain the value of `res`, but will be global, meaning you can access it from outside the `get` call.

Answer (score 0):

save the value in the global variable:

```
$.get("http://databasecall=json", {}, function (res) {
    window.myResult = res;
    ....
}
```

and use it afterwards

Answer (score 0):

You need to store it in a variable that has scope outside of the ajax return call.

So for example you could have:

```
           var resData;
```

at the top of an included javascript file

then replace your code with

```
$.get("http://databasecall=json",        {}, function(res) {
                                   $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
                                   if(res.length){
                                   resData = res;
                                   var s = "";
                                   for(var i=0; i<res.length; i++) {

                                   s+= "<li><a name=" + res[i].id + " href='" +      "javascript:openGoogle()" + "'>"  + res[i].showlink +  "</a></li>"; 

                                   }
```